# CSS Animation and advanced event triggering via Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, sprite-sheet

I have been going at this problem for a while now with not much luck. The goal is to use a single (horizontal) sprite sheet to have three different animation views based on button clicks.

1 - Default: Animate through ALL frames (This runs on page load and when Default button is clicked)

2 - View1: Animate through frame 1-12 (Runs when button view1 is clicked)

3 - View2: Animate through frame 1-36 (Runs when button view2 is clicked)

The challenge, though, is to begin the animation from the current frame no matter the view..This means if we are on frame 10 of view1 and button view2 is clicked, then the animation would begin from frame 10 and continue on through frame 36. I would imagine this requires having all of the views in one div and maybe overriding that?

My question: How can I access the current frame in a way that would allow me to perform these in-view animation updates (i.e., starting from the current frame regardless of current view)?

Here is a JSFiddle I put together: https://jsfiddle.net/Falmata/r4x4najh

`<br>`

Here is a JSFiddle I think would be useful:
https://jsfiddle.net/stephino/51fa3m17/

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: @zero298 updated with my exact question